# tensorflow 重みの値を利用して調査に使いたい。

Tags: tensorflow

tensorflow でCNN等をやっていて、重みの配列を取得したいのですが、どのようにすればよいでしょうか。
method があるのでしょうか？普通にはできない感じなのですが。。。

例えば、重みの配列を取得
w1 = 重みの配列を取得(tf.variable ...)
print （w1)

のようなソースを書きたいです。

Answer (score 1):

tensorflowのprintデバッグは、[このスライド](https://wookayin.github.io/tensorflow-talk-debugging/#24)が参考になると思います。

具体的には、session.runの引数に重みWのテンソルを指定して出力を得る、という手順です。

```
 mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)
 x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
 W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
 b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
 y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

 cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
     tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
 train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

 sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
 tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
 # Train
 display_step = 1
 for i in range(1000):
     batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
     # sess.runに重みのテンソルを指定
     w_out, _ = sess.run([W, train_step], feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
     # weightを出力
     if i % display_step == 0:
         print(w_out)
```

参考になれば幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

もう解決しているかもしれませんが。

```
v1 = tf.Variable([1,2,3,4])
sess = tf.Session()
w1 = sess.run(v1)
```

こんな感じで、Variableを取得できませんか？